# Number of ideals of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

[image]

For the first part, I manually calculated and found 7 ideals, which are proper and non-zero. Justification there can be principal ideals possible by $\langle2\rangle$ to $\langle11\rangle$, i.e., total 10 in number. but $\langle5\rangle$,$\langle7\rangle\langle11\rangle$ will give improper ideals.

I didn't understand the second part. I am doing graducation course. Please help me.

Comment: Note $\langle 1 \rangle$ also is not proper.  Also note $\langle 2 \rangle = \langle 10 \rangle$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

$I$ is and ideal of $R$ if for all $x \in I$ and $r \in R, xr \in I$

In addition to the trivial ideals: $2Z_{12}, 3Z_{12}, 4Z_{12}, 6Z_{12}$

$Z_{12}\oplus Z_{12}$ is the set of ordered pairs such that each is entry is in the respective ring.

$2Z_{12}\oplus Z_{12}$ is an ideal.

so is $2Z_{12}\oplus 0$ and $0\oplus 2Z_{12}$ how many do you think you have in total?

Comment: What will be the operation in the ring $Z_{12}\oplus Z_{12}$. I am having difficulty in imagin the ring $Z_{12}\oplus Z_{12}$. Could you please give a sample element?

Comment: $(1,4)$ is a member of the ring.  Since the ring is closed under addition $(1,4) + (1,4) = (2,8)$ is also in the ring.  As would be $3\times (1,4) = (3,0)$ and in this way generate a sub-ring.